# Node.js record keyboard events outside console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a keylogger using nodejs , can someone please guide on how to capture user keyboard strokes without some npm package using core nodejs? I just want to know which core node module should be used here for recording keyboard events outside the console.